# Can't logon to live dashboard

Tags: javascript, node.js

Okay, So I'm trying to make a function using puppeteer to change a twitch title using the live dashboard, but I can't even logon... What am I doing wrong?

```
async function titlechange(title) {

    var revisionInfo = await puppeteerResolver({
        folderName: '.chromium-browser-snapshots',
        hosts: ["https://storage.googleapis.com", "https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors"],
        retry: 3
    });
    var browser = await revisionInfo.puppeteer.launch({
        headless: false,
        executablePath: revisionInfo.executablePath
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

    const unput = 'body > div.ReactModalPortal > div > div > div > div.tw-border-radius-medium.tw-flex.tw-overflow-hidden > div > div > form > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div.tw-relative > input';
    const pwput = 'body > div.ReactModalPortal > div > div > div > div.tw-border-radius-medium.tw-flex.tw-overflow-hidden > div > div > form > div > div:nth-child(2) > div > div:nth-child(1) > div.password-input__container.tw-relative > div.tw-relative > input';
    const pgbtn = 'body > div.ReactModalPortal > div > div > div > div.tw-border-radius-medium.tw-flex.tw-overflow-hidden > div > div > form > div > div:nth-child(3) > button';
    const titleput = '#root > div > div.tw-flex.tw-flex-column.tw-flex-nowrap.tw-full-height > div.tw-flex.tw-flex-nowrap.tw-full-height.tw-overflow-hidden.tw-relative > div > div > div.drag-and-drop-layout-container__with-navs.scrollable-area > div.simplebar-scroll-content > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div.drag-and-drop-card-container.tw-border-b.tw-border-l.tw-border-r.tw-border-t.tw-c-background-base.tw-elevation-1.tw-flex.tw-flex-column.tw-lg-mg-b-2.tw-mg-b-1 > div.drag-and-drop-card-content.tw-relative > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div > div > textarea';
    const updatebtn = '#root > div > div.tw-flex.tw-flex-column.tw-flex-nowrap.tw-full-height > div.tw-flex.tw-flex-nowrap.tw-full-height.tw-overflow-hidden.tw-relative > div > div > div.drag-and-drop-layout-container__with-navs.scrollable-area > div.simplebar-scroll-content > div > div > div:nth-child(1) > div:nth-child(2) > div > div > div.drag-and-drop-card-container.tw-border-b.tw-border-l.tw-border-r.tw-border-t.tw-c-background-base.tw-elevation-1.tw-flex.tw-flex-column.tw-lg-mg-b-2.tw-mg-b-1 > div.drag-and-drop-card-content.tw-relative > div > div > div.tw-align-items-start.tw-flex.tw-flex-row.tw-full-width.tw-justify-content-start > button';
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://www.twitch.tv/**Nope**/dashboard/live');
    page.once('load', () => { 
        setTimeout( async () => {
            /* LOGIN */
            const userinput = await page.$(unput);
            const pwinput = await page.$(pwput);
            const loginbtn = await page.$(pgbtn);
            await userinput.click();
            await userinput.type("**Nope**", {delay: 150});
            await pwinput.click();
            await pwinput.type("**Nope**", {delay: 150});
            await loginbtn.click();
            /* LOGIN */

            /* UPDATE */
            const titinput = await page.$(titleput);
            const update = await page.$(updatebtn);
            var typdis = title;
            await titinput.click();
            await titinput.type(typdis);
            await update.click();
            browser.close();
            /* UPDATE */
        }, 5500);
    });
}
```

Also, I had some issues with the normal puppeteer so I found a package that got a mirror of chromium instead.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to understand why this question isn't suitable for SO. It's not clear what the problem is, and you seem to be asking about two separate issues (tiles and logon). You'll need to revise to be much more specific.

Comment: You don't understand what my problem is...
This was also pretty directed at people knowing twitch & puppeteer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Twitch has a pretty strict policy about using bots to login/register, what is happening is that it detects you using puppeter and is proping you to solve the captcha for proving you are not a robot. There are a few ways to work around it, but the simplest one would be to just grab cookies from a browser were you manually logged in and use it in puppeter.

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

const accountsCookie = {
    "name": "auth-token",
    "value": <**NOPE**>,
    "domain": ".twitch.tv",
    "path": "/",
    "httpOnly": false,
    "secure": true
}

(async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: ['--no-sandbox',
            '--proxy-server="direct://"',
            '--proxy-bypass-list=*'
        ]
    });
    const [page] = await browser.pages();
    await page.setCookie(accountsCookie);
    await page.goto('https://www.twitch.tv/**Nope**/dashboard/live');
})();
```

It seems that some of your selectors were wrong. Moreover with puppeteers limited window size the button is outside of the view. Your method fetches an element with selector, scrolls it into view if needed, and then uses page.mouse to click in the center of the element. The problem is that because the view (div) is animating the element's boundingBox() is changing, and between the time of asking for the box position, and completing the click() the element has moved or is not clickable. So you have to manually scroll to it before using the method.

```
(async () => {
    const revisionInfo = await puppeteerResolver({
        revision: "",
        detectionPath: "",
        folderName: '.chromium-browser-snapshots',
        hosts: ["https://storage.googleapis.com", "https://npm.taobao.org/mirrors"],
        retry: 3
    });

    const titleSelector = '#root > div > div.tw-flex.tw-flex-column.tw-flex-nowrap.tw-full-height > div.tw-flex.tw-flex-nowrap.tw-full-height.tw-overflow-hidden.tw-relative > div > div > div.drag-and-drop-layout-container__with-navs.scrollable-area > div.simplebar-scroll-content > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > div > textarea';
    const updatebtn = '#root > div > div.tw-flex.tw-flex-column.tw-flex-nowrap.tw-full-height > div.tw-flex.tw-flex-nowrap.tw-full-height.tw-overflow-hidden.tw-relative > div > div > div.drag-and-drop-layout-container__with-navs.scrollable-area > div.simplebar-scroll-content > div > div > div > div > div > div > div.drag-and-drop-card-container.tw-border-b.tw-border-l.tw-border-r.tw-border-t.tw-c-background-base.tw-elevation-1.tw-flex.tw-flex-column.tw-lg-mg-b-2.tw-mg-b-1 > div.drag-and-drop-card-content.tw-relative > div > div > div.tw-align-items-start.tw-flex.tw-flex-row.tw-full-width.tw-justify-content-start > button';

    const browser = await revisionInfo.puppeteer.launch({
        args: ['--no-sandbox'],
        executablePath: revisionInfo.executablePath
    });

    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.setCookie(accountsCookie);
    await page.goto('https://www.twitch.tv/**NOPE**/dashboard/live', {waitUntil: "networkidle0"});
    await page.type(titleSelector, "YOUR TITLE GOES HERE");
    await page.waitFor(2000);
    await page.evaluate(btn => {
        const updateButton = document.querySelector(btn);
        updateButton.scrollIntoView();
        updateButton.click();
    }, updatebtn);
    await page.waitFor(1000);
    await browser.close();
})();
```

I tested the provided code and it works on my machine even in headless mode.

Comment: According to puppeter docs this function is present.  The code i provided also works on my machine. If anything it has to be an issue with your mirror of chrome.

Comment: [page.setCookie](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pagesetcookiecookies)

Comment: can you provide some additional information on the puppeeter replacement package you used

Comment: Of course. - [Link](https://github.com/cenfun/puppeteer-chromium-resolver)

Comment: I fixed that Cookie thing somehow, and it loads the dashboard, the only problem now is that it doesn't register the tasks.. :/

Comment: page.evalutate is just giving null for everything inside.

Comment: any varaibles you want inside of it, you have to pass as a list of arguments, as you can see i got the updatebtn as an argument `page.evaluate((...args)=>{}, ...args)`

Comment: The error I get is ```Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of null``` - I made the viewport bigger and removed the scrolliNtoView,

I'm really confused...

Comment: i told you that your selectors were wrong, so you have to update them so that they actually point to the button

Comment: it clearly isnt if you are getting null instead of the button node, try using the command in the broswer manually to see outside of puppeteer, and to adjust it

Comment: Doing ```document.querySelector("**The long selector**");``` worked. (In the DevTool Console of course.)

Comment: are you sure you passed it correctly to the inside of callback function then?

Comment: This is some of what I got:
`await page.type(titleput, title);
    await page.waitFor(2000);
    await page.evaluate(btn => {
        const updateButton = document.querySelector(btn);
        updateButton.click();
    }, updatebtn);
    await page.waitFor(1000);
    await browser.close();`

Comment: As I said, not needed anymore as I made the viewport bigger.

Comment: I fixed it. Thanks for the help so far ;)

Comment: please let me know what did you change so i can edit my answer